# Retrieving xml parts uing Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This snippet of XML below is part of a much larger XML. I have tried over and over to get address line 1, 2,3  and City and State, postal code and country. I want to functionalize this so I can pick out 
 those addresses based on InvoiceHeader id="XXXX" however I keep running into a wall. 
I have tried the following query below or something along the lines but I keep getting an error *object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

here is my query can someone please point out my obvious mistake.

```
 IEnumerable<string> partNos =
            from item in PurchaseOrderXml.Descendants("RemitTo").Descendants("Address")
            where (string)item.Attribute("id").Value == "23951768"
            select (string)item;



<Invoice>
    <InvoiceHeader id="23951768" status="InProcess">
        <InvoiceName />
        <InvoiceNumber>23951768</InvoiceNumber>
        <InvoiceDate>2014-09-26 00:00:00.0</InvoiceDate>
        <DueDate>2014-10-26 00:00:00.0</DueDate>
        <SupplierInvoiceNo>534254504</SupplierInvoiceNo>
        <InvoiceType>Invoice</InvoiceType>
      <Supplier id="3825405">
        <ContactInfo type="main">
              <Address>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="1">Post </AddressLine>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="2">30 Street</AddressLine>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="3">30 Street</AddressLine>
                <City>Saint Louis</City>
                <State>MO</State>
                <PostalCode>63103-2530</PostalCode>
                <Country isoCountryCode="US">United States</Country>
            </Address>
        </ContactInfo>
    </Supplier>
        <BillTo>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine lineNumber="1">vvvv</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine lineNumber="2">vvvv</AddressLine>
            <City>Philadelphia</City>
            <State>PA</State>
            <PostalCode>19222</PostalCode>
            <Country isoCountryCode="US">United States</Country>
        </Address>
          </BillTo>
        <RemitTo>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="1">P O BOX 535182</AddressLine>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="2" />
                <AddressLine lineNumber="3" />
                <City>ATLANTA</City>
                <State>GA</State>
                <PostalCode>303535182</PostalCode>
                <Country isoCountryCode="US">United States</Country>
            </Address>
        </RemitTo>
     </InvoiceHeader>
</Invoice>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your item range variable corresponds to an Address element which does not have an id attribute. Instead, you need a query which first finds (or filters) the appropriate InvoiceHeader and then looks for Address element desendents of the matched InvoiceHeader.

Here is an example for finding the InvoiceHeader:

```
var Header = PurchaseOrderXml.Descendants("InvoiceHeader")
.FirstOrDefault(header => (string)header.Attribute("id").Value == headerId);
```

You can check if the Header is found (`Header != null`).  Once you have the Header, do whatever you need to within the scope of that given element. Example:

```
var RemitToAddress = Header.Descendants("RemitTo").Descendants("Address").FirstOrDefault();
```

You may want to inspect other elements in the Header, and so splitting the queries up into parts like this keeps your intent clear.

Also note that I've used `Descendants`, but you may also use `Elements` if it matches your schema better.

Another example, to get the `AddressLine` elements and concatenate them, you might try something along the lines of:

```
IEnumerable<string> AddressLines = RemitToAddress.Elements("AddressLine")
.OrderBy(line => (int)line.Attribute("lineNumber"))
.Select(line => line.Value);

var AddressText = string.Join("\n", AddressLines);
```

Comment: so I need two querys?

Comment: I'll update to provide an example, but yet, conceptually you need two queries, and separating them out as such probably makes sense.

Comment: an example would be much appreciated. I'm trying to learn to fish :-D.

Comment: Michael this is very clean thank you. just one more question. the var remitoAddress value ends with the 3 address line concatenated. Is there any way to logically separated them? Sorry for my stupid question

Comment: Sure, you can query into the `RemitToAddress` element further.  I'll update with another example.

Comment: clean and easy to understand I totally get your approach thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var result = xdoc.Root.Descendants("InvoiceHeader")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "23951768")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("Address"))
    .Select(x =>
    {
       {
         var addressLine1 = x.Elements("AddressLine")
                        .FirstOrDefault(z => z.Attribute("lineNumber").Value == "1");
         var addressLine2 = x.Elements("AddressLine")
                        .FirstOrDefault(z => z.Attribute("lineNumber").Value == "2");
         var addressLine3 = x.Elements("AddressLine")
                        .FirstOrDefault(z => z.Attribute("lineNumber").Value == "3");
         return new
         {
            AddressLine1 = addressLine1 != null ? addressLine1.Value : String.Empty,
            AddressLine2 = addressLine2 != null ? addressLine1.Value : String.Empty,
            AddressLine3 = addressLine3 != null ? addressLine1.Value : String.Empty,
            City = x.Element("City").Value,
            State = x.Element("State").Value
            PostalCode = x.Element("PostalCode").Value,
            Country= x.Element("Country").Value,
          };
        }
    });
```

Comment: this seems to work with the smaller xml I posted above but I'm having problems with the original xml. the error I get is sequence contains no matching elements? any ideas?

Comment: Are all the other elements similar to this in your large XML? I have considered you can multiple `Address` in `RemitTo` node. Sequence contains no elements no element is matching your passed criteria, you can debug and let me know.

Comment: I have multiple addresses in my larger xml I updated my post with a more relevant example. I think the multiple addresses might be what is making the linq query brake?

Comment: if you look at my xml now youll notice I need to get the descendants for the remit to address.

Comment: @miguel - Its happening because you don't have address line 3 in first address node, and we are trying to fetch its value so it will throw null reference exception inside and no results outside, just check for null and then fetch value., I will update that code